# Deregister default wp-admin css on login screen only?

Tags: login, css

I have a question about deregistering 'wp-admin' styles specifically on the login screen.

If I just globally run:

```
<?php wp_deregister_style( 'wp-admin' ); ?>
```

my login screen will have no styles.

If I run a function like:

```
function remove_default_styles() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wp-admin' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_default_styles' );
```

this removes the styles successfully in the admin area, but not on the login page.

However, if I run the same function with a login action, like so:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_default_styles' );
```

it has no effect.

Does anyone know how to deregister the default styles just on the login screen?

Thanks

Comment: Oh.  It *seems* like the action I needed was 'login_init'.  Like so:

    function login_remove_scripts() {
        wp_deregister_style( 'wp-admin' );
    }
    add_action( 'login_init', 'login_remove_scripts' );

Comment: Please write a full answer, so I can vote for your solution. And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks, toscho.  I am new here.  Great resource! I'm so new, in fact, that I have to wait several hours before I'm allowed to answer myself.  That's why I did a comment for now.  I'll come back.  Thanks for your welcome  :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh.  It *seems* like the action I needed was 'login_init'.  Like so:

```
function login_remove_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'wp-admin' );
}
add_action( 'login_init', 'login_remove_scripts' );
```